# Excel: Running two functions behind one another

Tags: excel, excel-2010, cube

I have an Excel problem. I'm getting my data from an analytic-cube and if there is no value he leaves the cell empty. I want to check if the cell is empty and fill it with a "0"

```
=CUBEVALUE(...)&IF(ISBLANK(G28);0)
```

If the cell is blank, he fills it with a 0. That's ok and it's working, but he fills everything with 0, even if there is a Cubevalue. How can I run these functions behind one another?

Comment: is that formula in G28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps try

```
=IFERROR(CUBEVALUE(...)+0,0)
```